# I have a problem with a camera from a robot using a raspberry

Tags: picamera

Recently I started a project (for school) and it's a recon robot and it has 2 cameras, one on a robotic arm and the other on the top of the body. My problem is, I want the top camera to spin freely but the camera cable will be on the way and for the arm, it's the same proble, I want the arm to spin freely.

So is there a way to connect those cables diferently ?

Comment: What connectors do the two cameras use? What cameras are they?

Comment: you could spin a mirror